# Forbidden when calling api from custom domain registered in CloudFlare

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, cloudflare, api-gateway

I have a working API-Gateway solution, when I call the API-Gateway directly I get a 200 response as expected.  We use CloudFlare as our DNS provider so I have registered the endpoint there and got a 403 "Forbidden".

After reading though various posts I have set up a custom domain in the API-Gateway, using a CloudFlare generated certificate, registered in the us-east-1 region, added a base path mapping for the API-Gateway stage (v1), and received the cloudfront.net url which I added to CloudFlare, the API registration now looks like this.

CNAME api.staging  is an alias of d1xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net

I get a 200 when calling the API-Gateway directly, but still receive a 403 Forbidden when calling the api endpoint though CloudFlare using the "api.staging.domain name" and also when calling the api through the generated cloudfront.net endpoint.  fairly new to the domain registration side of devopps so any help would be great.

Comment: Does the "api.staging.domain" mean the custom domain you added in AWS ApiGateway?

Comment: yes I added that to the custom domain in aws, it is actually the domain we want to use domain (is a place holder for our actual domain :) which is a co.uk style domain

Comment: Are you omitting the stage from the path when calling the cloudflare url?

Comment: did u find a soliution  ?